# Does Friend-Ship have sexual connotations?

Tags: word-usage

In modern usage "shipping" refers to basically two people having a love attraction or psychological humpy humpy time and possibly procreating so basically I'm asking

Does the term friendship have sexual connotations, because it is a type of shipping?

Comment: Shipping having sexual connotations? Who would have thought it?  I though that was roll-on roll-off ferries.. :-)

Comment: Related: [Is “shipping” today's equivalent of “matchmaking”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432720/is-shipping-todays-equivalent-of-matchmaking)

Comment: Please have a look at the use of the suffix [**-ship**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-ship).

Comment: Definitely not. As you say, _shipping_ is a modern coinage, whereas words like _friendship, kingship_ etc. go back centuries.

Comment: Connotation is in the mind of the person reading the connotations into a word etc (contrast the article Mari-Lou references with Kate's comment). It's probably better to ask about the prevalence of connotation. Or even the state of mind of someone seeing innuendo everywhere.

Comment: I guess that is what all those frisky bunnies in Watership Down were doing after all...

Comment: Humpy humpy time? Do you mean fucking?  You are allowed to use the whole gamut of English in posts, just not in titles. Still, that’s a euphemism I’ve not seen before. I’ll try it at the next dinner party I attend and see how it goes down.

Answer (score 3):

No. The ordinary definition of friendship predates the slang usage of "ship"- therefore friendship has no lewd connotations.

Comment: The answer could be improved by the addition of a reference for the claim.

Answer (score -2):

Shipping has to do with sending something on a ship, as a means of transport. The *ship* you refer to is the syllable at the end of words like friendship or kingship. The -*ship* here refers to the sate of being friends or being a king. Nothing more. 
What modern usage will do is anyone's guess. Reference to *The Love Boat* is needed.

Comment: In this context, "shipping" is a neologism that refers to having a relationship. The Q asks if the meaning can be extended to any word with _ship_ as a suffix.

Comment: Making puns about phyiscal ships and the 'ship' suffix is nothing new. Try the 4th verse of [The First Lord's Song](http://www.guntheranderson.com/v/data/firstlor.htm) by Gilbert and Sullivan from 1878. _"
Of legal knowledge I acquired such a grip
That they took me into the partnership
And that junior partnership I ween
Was the only ship that I ever had seen
But that kind of ship so suited me
That now I am the Ruler of the Queen's Navy"_